# ListView - get adjacent items of the clicked item

Tags: java, android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I am trying to make a ListView where you can have no more than 4 items clicked at once. 
These items have to be adjacent to each other.

When I click my first item, I want to see if the previous OR the following item is clicked already.

Note: When I click an item, I change the background color. So if I want to tell if an item is clicked or not, I just want to check the background color.

```
public void OnItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View, view, int position, long id){

    View currentItem = view;
    currentItem.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.li_gradient);

    // How do I get the view in front of and behind currentItem
    // to check their current background color? (Assuming they exist)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this inside your adapter class, the model item need to have a background resource property.

Just cast the adapter, get the previous or next item, set the new background and notify the listView

```
public void OnItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View, view, int position, long id){

    YourAdapterClass adapter = (YourAdapterClass) parent.getAdapter();

    // TODO check if is a valid position
    YourItem item = (YourItem) adapter.getItem(position-1);
    item.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.li_gradient);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that if the activity is recreated (because of configuration change for example) or if the list view is redrawn (for example when it is notified of a change) it will not automatically know about the changes made to the view in the onClick method and the background changes could be lost.

I would make a custom AdapterView with methods like itemSelected(int i), clearAllSelected(), getSelectedItems(), etc and make the adapterview the single point of responsibility for tracking and maintaining those changes and for rendering the background.